# Execute custom annotation in webflux application before method execution

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-aop

How can I avoid using the .block() method in the aspect component while making sure the annotation is completed before the method where is called starts executing?

I have some validations that needs to be executed before some methods from a service are executed

I have created a custom annotation, that I can use to annotate each method where I want to perform the validation

The Annotation looks like this:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface PerformValidationInterface{

}
```

The Aspect method that i want to be executed looks like this:

```
    @Before("execution(* *.*(..)) && @annotation(performValidation)")
    public Mono<Void> doBeforeMethod(JoinPoint joinPoint, PerformValidationInterface performValidation) {

        return validationService.validateObject(object)
                         //i am using defer becaue I don't want to evaluate the switchIfEmpty()  if the validateObject() returns something 
                         .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer( 
                              () -> anotherService.checkIfObjectExists(object)))      
                         .block();
}
```

```
public ValidationService {

    public Mono<Object> validateObject(Object object) {
            //perform object validation
            if (objectIsValid) { 
                return Mono.just(object) 
            } else { 
                return Mono.empty()
            }
    }

}
```

```
public FooService {



     //How can I avoid using the .block() method in the aspect component while making sure the annotation is completed before the barMethod starts executing
      @PerformValidation
      public Mono<Bar> barMethod(Object arg1, Object arg2 ) {
         //do some stuff and return a Mono<Bar>

      }
}
```

Comment: Mono<Void> from the aspect? So every method that is annotated should not return anything?

Comment: I am not sure, does it matter what the aspect is retuning? 

Methods that will be annotated are returning different objects

Comment: Well as the code looks now, every function using the annotation will return ”nothing”, basically discarding the returns, and if thats what you want….

Comment: for example in the ```FooService``` the annotated method returns a Mono<Bar>. The things is that i don't care what the aspect is returning, i only want the code from aspect method to be executed always before the annotated method

Comment: ah its an `@Before` and not an `@Around` my mistake, but `return validationService.validateObject(object)` what is `object`

Comment: It's something that I am retrieving somehow using the ```joinPoint``` argument and a SpelExpressionParser.

My challenge is how can I be sure that the code inside of the aspect is executed before  the method that is annotated starts executing, without using ```.block()```.  With ```.block()``` the order of execution is performed as wanted but I don't really want to use ```.block()``` just used it to prototype.

Comment: If i remove ```.block()``` the code  inside aspect is not executed at all, because no one subscribes to it, i think

Comment: since this is a void function no one will subscribe to it, i would recommend that you use the `@Around`annotation instead so that you can return from it and becomes part of the reactive flow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246943/discussion-between-robertsci-and-toerktumlare).

Comment: A ` @Before` advice has return type `void`, same goes for `@After`. Only `@Around` advices return something. So your code does not make any sense.

Comment: How would you use the @Around to return the subscribtion from the aspect and then use the subscribtion in the annotated method?

Comment: i have no idea what you mean when you say __return a subscription__ functions return _types_ and asking how `@Around` "works" is a big subject and im not going to write your complete implementation. I suggest you google how `@Around` "works" and try to build it yourself and then ask a new question if you get stuck

Comment: Please do not answer a question by editing it. Instead, please post an answer. After some waiting time, you can even accept your own answer in order to mark the problem as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution looks like this:

```java
@Around("execution(* *.*(..)) && @annotation(performValidation)")
public Mono doBeforeMethod(JoinPoint joinPoint, PerformValidationInterface performValidation) {
  return validationService
    .validateObject(object)
    //i am using defer becaue I don't want to evaluate the switchIfEmpty() if the validateObject() returns something 
    .switchIfEmpty(
      Mono.defer( 
        () -> anotherService.checkIfObjectExists(object)
      )
    )
    .then((Mono) joinPoint.proceed());
}
```

`.then()` -> will wait until your validation logic(or some other logic) is completed, THEN will call the `joinPoint.proceed()`

`joinPoint.proceed()` -> will continue the execution of the annotated method